# encrypting an email using an EC X509 certificate

Tags: java, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, smime

I'm trying to use BouncyCastle's SMIME package to create an encrypted message using ECDSA X509 certificates.  According to BouncyCastle's release notes, this has been supported since 1.32 (I'm using 1.46), but I keep getting an exception stating that no cipher can be found for the ECDSA OID.

> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: exception wrapping content key:
>   cannot create cipher: Cannot find any provider supporting
>   1.2.840.10045.2.1

Here is a snippet from one of the test certificates I am using

```
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=bob@example.com
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withECDSA, OID = 1.2.840.10045.4.3.2

  Key:  EC Public Key
```

The code I am using to create the encrypted message looks like this:

```
// allow the use of the BC JCE
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator gen = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();
JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator rig = new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(cert);
gen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(rig);

MimeBodyPart msg = new MimeBodyPart();
msg.setText(message);

MimeBodyPart mp = gen.generate(
    msg,
    new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(
        CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC).setProvider("BC").build());

Properties props = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

// TODO: This is incorrect.  Perhaps AKA is better?
String to = cert.getSubjectDN().getName();

Address fromUser = new InternetAddress(from);
Address toUser = new InternetAddress(to);

MimeMessage body = new MimeMessage(session);
body.setFrom(fromUser);
body.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
body.setSubject("example encrypted message");
body.setContent(mp.getContent(), mp.getContentType());
body.saveChanges();

body.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filename));
```

I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I'm not seeing it right now.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas Pornin suggested (above), ECDH needed to be used to make this work.  So instead of using a JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator, it was necessary to use a JceKeyAgreeRecipientInfoGenerator.

```
SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator gen = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();
JceKeyAgreeRecipientInfoGenerator rig = new JceKeyAgreeRecipientInfoGenerator(CMSAlgorithm.ECDH_SHA1KDF, senderPrivateKey, senderPublicKey, CMSAlgorithm.AES128_WRAP);
rig.setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
rig.addRecipient(recipientX509Certificate);
gen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(rig);

MimeBodyPart msg = new MimeBodyPart();
msg.setText("This is a secret message");

MimeBodyPart mp = gen.generate(msg, new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC).setProvider("BC").build());

Properties props = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

String to = "bob@example.com";

Address fromUser = new InternetAddress("alice@example.com");
Address toUser = new InternetAddress(to);

MimeMessage body = new MimeMessage(session);
body.setFrom(fromUser);
body.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
body.setSubject("example encrypted message");
body.setContent(mp.getContent(), mp.getContentType());
body.saveChanges();

body.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/encrypted.msg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

ECDSA is a signature algorithm, not an encryption or key exchange algorithm. In order to encrypt a message, you need the recipient's RSA or Diffie-Hellman key (possibly ECDH).

Comment: Cant an EC Public Key be used for both ECDSA and ECDH?  I assumed that using SHA256withECDSA for the signature algorithm wouldnt restrict the usage of the key to just signatures.  Is that wrong?

Comment: An ECDSA key and an ECDH key share the same structure; however, they usually need distinct life cycles and storage policies (e.g. you usually want to keep a backup and/or escrow of the encryption key, to avoid catastrophic data loss scenarios, but you certainly do not want to do it for signature keys; also, consequences of a private key compromise are quite distinct depending on the key type). Many X.509 certificates explicitly state the intended usage (Key Usage extension), which forbids using a signature key for encryption.

Comment: Yes, I came across one of your previous explanations of [ECDSA and ECDH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969570/is-there-a-difference-between-ecdh-and-ecdsa-keys), but I thought as long as I marked the certificate's Key Usage for everything (thats a separate issue) that it would be allowed to be used.  In this case, I believe something else is going on though, because the section of code that is failing in BC is simply extracting the OID of the public key and passing that into a Cipher.getInstance().  Since the OID is for the EC "key type", I wouldnt expect a valid Cipher to ever be found